# chaining parameters to a JS library

Tags: javascript, function, return, bcrypt

I was trying to use bcrypt like this.

```js
var token = bcrypt.hash(info, 10, function (err, hash) {
  if (err) return null;
  return hash;
});
//pass the info param to token whenever I call token
token("test");
```

Can someone explain to me if this is possible, if so, is it a good practice?
I basically want to do this because for some reason, `req.session.destroy` doesn't really remove session from firefox but it works on chrome.

Comment: not sure about the bcrypt package and that hash function, but javascript is absolutely asynchronous and it will send that inner function off to the ether, and carry on it's merry way.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue today. In a regular function I need to call a promise function and return its value, example, ```const x = Promise.resolve(1); const y= ()=>{//here I can't use await because then I'd have to make y into async and I can use .then() because I wouldn't be able to return the value of x}```
Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with async/await function call . `hash` only accept string so better use `toString()` method on call

```
const token  = async (val) => await bcrypt.hash(val.toString(),10);
```

For session

```
app.use('/logout', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.destroy(() => {
      res.redirect('/')
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/')
  }
})
```

Comment: ```var tokenGen = async function (info) {
  return await bcrypt.hash(info.toString(), 10);
}```this is how i did it. Thanks

Comment: for node ES6 Supported better use arrow function like my answer

Comment: for `req.session.destroy `  is working good. better check the callback `req.session.destroy(()=>{ console.log(req.session) })`

Comment: ```router.get("/logout", function (req, res, next) {
  req.session.user.token = undefined;
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      req.session.user.token = null;
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});``` is how i implemented as it was not working with firefox.

Comment: apologies but how is that drastically different from my implementation?

Comment: i dont know how you validate the session . for your code you are just update the user object token .i just post general method of session destroy.Check if that code was working .you can change as your need .as per code , session destroy reset the entire session.so need to set token value before `session.destroy`